# Social polling apps

Tags: survey

Looking for social polling apps like [Pyne](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pyne-poll-world.-ask-questions/id884287785?mt=8), [Straw](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/straw/id925623439?mt=8), [aaVOTE](http://www.aavote.net/), [Mentimeter](https://www.mentimeter.com) for Android, iOS or Facebook.

App where:

- user can *post questions* relating relationships, social life, friendship, life
- user can *add optional answers* to the existing answers
- user can *select answer* according to his/her preference
- user can make distinction among his / her votes by scoring / ordering them

It is also interesting what advantage /  difference they have.

Comment: Must an app be available for both platforms, Android *and* iOS?

Comment: Well, you could use a web-based solution like Google Forms or [Mentimeter](https://www.mentimeter.com/)

Comment: @Huey thanks, amazing site, this and similar I am looking for